# how would someone install pytorch using pip on python 3.9?

Tags: python-3.x, pytorch

when i tried the command the website used `pip install torch==1.7.0+cpu torchvision==0.8.1+cpu torchaudio===0.7.0 -f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html`

and it returned the error code

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement torch==1.7.0+cpu (from versions: 0.1.2, 
0.1.2.post1, 0.1.2.post2)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for torch==1.7.0+cpu
```

even when i change the code to satisfy the requirement it comes up with more errors like
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tools.setup_helpers'

Comment: run this `pip install torch== -f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html` and check is there version `1.7.0+cpu` is available.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Searching for "1.7.0" at the https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html page, you can see that only wheels for Python 3.6, 3.7, and 3.8 are available.

So there is no official wheel for Python 3.9.

Update:
PyTorch currently doesn't work with Python 3.9, there are known issues being resolved: https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/47776

Comment: @Jacobwhite ask PyTorch team if it's possible to provide the wheel for Python 3.9, or find maybe there is unofficial wheel somewhere, or build from source.

Comment: how would i build it from source?

Comment: I've updated my answer, currently PyTorch will not work with Python 3.9, even if you build it from source.